# Import data from Database to JS file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am new to .js files and their use, I am trying to update charts that uses JS. What I need or trying to do is import information from my database to use it in my JS file to populate the chart. Here is the chart code and file name.

File Name charjs_custom.js

```
/*Polar chart*/
    var polarElem = document.getElementById("polarChart");

    var data3 = {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                20,
                16,
                7,
                3,
                40
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#7E81CB",
                "#1ABC9C",
                "#B8EDF0",
                "#B4C1D7",
                "#01C0C8"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#a1a4ec",
                "#2adab7",
                "#a7e7ea",
                "#a5b0c3",
                "#10e6ef"
            ],
            label: 'My dataset' // for legend
        }],
        labels: [
            "Blue",
            "Green",
            "Light Blue",
            "grey",
            "Sea Green"
        ]
    };

    new Chart(polarElem, {
        data: data3,
        type: 'polarArea',
        options: {
            elements: {
                arc: {
                    borderColor: ""
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I need to alter the "data" and "label" sections using information from my DB, from what I have read I need to create a php file to retrieve the informationbut how do i convert it to JS and how do I tell it what information to use in the JS file. Also linking the "data" and "label" sections so the information will correspond to my tables

Tables I want to use is: make: id~count

File Name chart_test.php

```
<?php

//database
$host="my_host"; // Host name 
$username="my_username"; // Mysql username 
$password="my_password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="my_database"; // Database name 

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM bureau GROUP BY make ");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
 print json_encode($data);

 ?>
```

Comment: You are using JSON, so I would further that reading you mentioned on retrieving data from MySQL via PHP and create an array, then use `json_encode` to create the configuration/dataset that you're looking for.

Comment: I submitted an edit request to remove your database credentials from your script. Be careful when posting code that has information like that.

Comment: Which fields in your database correspond to which elements of the chart?

Comment: @Keith thanks tired and missed that

Comment: Make will correspond to label and data I want to get total value of the make field, that I can get using grouping or count

Answer (score 0):

you can interchange data between php backend and js frontend using JSON format. However i urge you to use nodejs as a backend service. it will integrate seamlessly with your js code.

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing anything about your data source, it would typically work like the following.

```
<?php
// Lets say your managed to convert your data from your database into something like.
$graph = [
    'data'       => [20, 16, 7, 3, 40],
    'background' => ['#7E81CB', '#1ABC9C', '#B8EDF0', '#B4C1D7', '#01C0C8'],
    'hover'      => ['#a1a4ec', '#2adab7', '#a7e7ea', '#a5b0c3', '#10e6ef'],
    'labels'     => ['Blue', 'Green', 'Light Blue', 'Grey', 'Sea Green']
];

?>

var polarElem = document.getElementById("polarChart");

var data3 = {
    datasets: [{
        data: <?php echo json_encode($graph['data']); ?>,
        backgroundColor: <?php echo json_encode($graph['background']); ?>,
        hoverBackgroundColor: <?php echo json_encode($graph['hover']); ?>,
        label: 'My dataset'
    }],
    labels: <?php echo json_encode($graph['labels']); ?>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the mapping of the database, I would do:

```
<?php
//database
$host="my_host"; // Host name 
$username="my_username"; // Mysql username 
$password="my_password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="my_database"; // Database name 

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM bureau GROUP BY make ");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


// Define configuration array
$config = array(
   'datasets' => array(
        array(
            'data' => array(),
            'backgroundColor' => array(), // This could be statically loaded, or dynamic if the DB has colors
            'hoverBackgroundColor' => array(), // This could be statically loaded, or dynamic if the DB has colors
            'label' => 'My Dataset'
        )
    ),
    'labels' => array()
);

// Loop through database result and add
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($config['labels'], $row['make']); // Add label
    array_push($config['datasets'][0]['data'], $row['totalValue']); // Add value
}

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
echo json_encode($config);
```

What you ultimately do with that config depends on how you're loading this chart. It could be an AJAX request that you would then use the result of in place of `data3` such as:

```
$.get( "chart_test.php", function( data ) {
    new Chart(polarElem, {
        data: data,
        type: 'polarArea',
        options: {
            elements: {
                arc: {
                    borderColor: ""
                }
            }
        }
    });
}, "json" );
```

Or embedded into a php file so that instead of printing the `json_encode($config);` you would create the entire script:

```
new Chart(polarElem, {
        data: <?= json_encode($config) ?>,
        type: 'polarArea',
        options: {
            elements: {
                arc: {
                    borderColor: ""
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It all depends on the setup you have thus far.